# How can I detach a gdb session from outside?

Tags: c++, c, linux, gdb

I start a gdb session in the background with a command like this:

```
gdb --batch --command=/tmp/my_automated_breakpoints.gdb -p pid_of_proces> &> /tmp/gdb-results.log &
```

The `&` at the end lets it run in the background (and the shell is immediately closed afterwards as this command is issued by a single `ssh` command).

I can find out the `pid` of the `gdb` session with `ps -aux | grep gdb`.

**However: How can I gracefully detach this gdb session from the running process just like I would if I had the terminal session in front of me with the `(gdb) detach` command?**

When I kill the gdb session (and not the running process itself) with `kill -9 gdb_pid`, I get unwanted `SIGABRT`s afterwards in the running program.

A restart of the service is too time consuming for my purpose.

In case of a successful debugging session with this automated script I could use a detach command inside the batch script. This is however not my case: I want to detach/quit the running gdb session when there are some errors during the session, so I would like to gracefully detach gdb by hand from within another terminal session.

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/31824/291769

Comment: I assume your batch command is running in a loop? Otherwise it should end of its accord. If that is the case one workaround would be to have the loop periodically check for the presence (or absence) of a file. If the file is detected then the loop should exit and detach. Then it would be a simple matter to "signal" gdb by creating (or deleting) the file.

Comment: @kaylum interesting idea! However, the batch command is simply hanging in the `continue` and waiting for breakpoints to be matched by the service's actions. So there is no real loop, it's just waiting...

Comment: Can you show us a stack trace from the SIGABRT? As far as I can tell, the worst case - GDB doesn't remove breakpoints and the target continues after the detach - would result in the target getting SIGTRAP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you run the `gdb` command from terminal #1 in the background, you can always bring `gdb` back into foreground by running the command `fg`. Then, you can simply CTRL+C and `detach` as always to stop the debugging session gracefully.

Assuming that terminal #1 is now occupied by something else and you cannot use it, You can send a `SIGHUP` signal to the `gdb` process to detach it:

```
sudo kill -s SIGHUP $(pidof gdb)
```

(Replace the `$(pidof gdb)` with the actual PID if you have more than one gdb instance)

Comment: I like the `SIGHUP` approach, but sadly it did not resolve the `SIGABRT` signal inside the service. Maybe killing gdb is not even causally related to it, I just observed a pattern here.

Comment: @ElectRocnic, I just ran a quick test on my machine, and sending SIGHUP to GDB while the underlying application is running will detach it and SIGCONT the application. Can you explain: "I want to detach/quit the running gdb session when there are some errors during the session". Are these errors in the debugging session?

Comment: The error is an unexpected EOF during some io handling on the second API request to the debugged app after I detach gdb during the first request. It might really just be the service itself. I actually believe your answer is correct.