# about return (count), count = 0;

Tags: c++, c

so after

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    int n;
    n = _strlen_recursion("Corbin Coleman");
    printf("%d\n", n);
}
int _strlen_recursion(char *s)
{
   static int count = 0;    
   count++;  
   return (count), count = 0;
}
```

where the comma operator is in action
`0` can be seen on screen. Why?

So the real question is : does `return` have `()` overload  as say `sizeof` does?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other

Comment: @sweenish did you read it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the comma operator , do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52550/what-does-the-comma-operator-do)

Comment: Do not tag questions both C and C++ unless they ask about a difference or interaction between the two languages.

Comment: @EricPostpischil but dude why then we do not see you there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66358126/how-can-i-detach-a-gdb-session-from-outside  or there but i see you here instead? tell me

Comment: @АлексейНеудачин: I do not see or examine every question and have no obligation to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return` is not similar to `sizeof`. The operand of `sizeof` is either a type in parentheses or an expression.

A `return` statement has only an expression (or nothing). Parentheses are not part of the grammar of a return statement. Parentheses may be present only because they are part of the expression.

In `return (count), count = 0;`, the expression is `(count), count = 0`. That is a comma expression. It evaluates `(count)`, discards the resulting value, then evaluates `count = 0`. The value of that is the value assigned, 0, so that is the value of the comma expression, so 0 is returned.

Comment: >The operand of sizeof is either a type in parentheses or an expression.        It's not right ofc because     `short a;
    short c;
    long long t;
    a = sizeof (t) , c;
    printf("%d\n", a);`    we have `8`

Comment: so it's real `()` overload as i said. it's not for type

Comment: @АлексейНеудачин [`sizeof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof) is an operator that has two versions (one for types, the other for expressions). When used with types, the operand of `sizeof` must be enclosed in parentheses. When used with expressions, the operand of `sizeof` need not be enclosed in parentheses, but of course, since a parenthesized expression is still an expression, it works with parentheses as well. On the other hand, [`return`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/return) is not an operator at all; it is a statement. Statements do not have "overloads".

Comment: @heapunderrun And you too? If it'll be true what you're saying then code in comments above will come to `2` , not to `8` . Compiler or whatever pulls out `sizeof()` overload there

Comment: this page now contains enough info to make it more than clear

Comment: @АлексейНеудачин When you write `a = sizeof (t) , c;`, the operand of the assignment is only `sizeof (t)`, not the whole `sizeof (t) , c;`, in other words, it goes like `(a = sizeof (t)) , c;`, not like `a = (sizeof (t) , c);`. The same result you'll get if you write `a = sizeof t , c;`. The reason is that `=` operator has higher [precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than `,` operator. Comma has the lowest precedence, if you look at the table I've linked.

Comment: @heapunderrun  looks like you'd wanted to say different thing, but made a mistake.this thing you'd wanted to say is that `=` has higher precedence than sizeof's space (whatever it called). It's not about comma here. I'll check  it on return but i've thinkin it has same precedence as square bracket.Which is to say , highest possible priority

Comment: or may be comma plays some role also nevertheless

Comment: @АлексейНеудачин No, the `=` operator has *lower* precedence than `sizeof` operator, but higher than `,` operator. The `=` operator has one of the lowest priorities (but still not lower than `,` operator, see that table).

Comment: I've talked about space right after `sizeof` that it has highest precedence, not about `=` operator. So check performed by my code above really shows nothing. And i do not know how to check this. I've found some stuff on that in gcc github repo but it doesn't make it more clear. https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/16e2427f50c208dfe07d07f18009969502c25dc8/gcc/c/ChangeLog#L2618    So may be you're right

Answer (score 2):

In the [return statement](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/return) `return (count), count = 0;`,

> ```
> attr(optional) return expression(optional) ;  (1)
> ```

The expression is `(count), count = 0`, as [comma operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator), the 1st operand `(count)` is evaluated and the result is discarded, then the 2nd operand `count = 0` is evaluated, its value `0` is returned as the return value of the omma operator, and returned as the return value of `_strlen_recursion()` later.

Comment: as i know `return` is similar to `sizeof` so there's `return(...);` and `return ...;`

Comment: @АлексейНеудачин `return(...);` and `return ...;` have the same effect, e.g. `return (count), count = 0;` is same as `return ((count), count = 0);`.

Comment: it's possible only if either comma has higher precedence than a round bracket or there's some specific stuff on `return()` vs `return ..`

Comment: @АлексейНеудачин If you want `count = 0` to be evaluated after `return count`, I think it's impossible in one line..

Answer (score 1):

The comma acts as a binary operator in C, the same way `+`, `-`, `&`, and all the other operators in C do. It takes two operands and acts as a sequence point. The left operand, `(count)` in your example, is evaluated, the result is then discarded. From here, the right operand, `count = 0`, is evaluated and its return value is returned. In your example, the left operand has no side-effects, so it is essentially useless. The line `return (count), count = 0;` is equivalent to the two lines

```
(void) (count);
return count = 0;
```

Note that `count = 0` is an assignment, and in C, assignments return the value assigned, so in this case 0 is returned form this expression, and ultimately the function.

Comment: this means that comma op has higher precedence than a round bracket. thats may be but i didn't see stuff like that before

Comment: @АлексейНеудачин The comma has lower precedence than parentheses, I didn't mean to imply the opposite, let me know which part of my answer did and I'll clarify.

Comment: because you're talking that compiler (or preprocessor) pulls `return smth` overload instead of `return (smth)`

Comment: Let me break down the return expression exactly. Return expressions evaluate the operand, and then return it from the function, so it has to evaluate the expression `(count), count = 0`, this expression is evaluated via the rules mentioned in my answer, and the result of this expression is 0, thus the return value is 0. Also note this step is in the compiler, not the preprocessor.